# If one check box is checked another check box will check

Tags: javascript

I have plenty of check boxes with different value.

```
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='id[]'> <input type='checkbox' name='title[]'>
}
```

How to do if i check the check box name id and check box name title will check too?

Comment: your question is unclear.. try to explain it little bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='id[]']").on('change',function(){
var isChecked = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='id[]']").prop('checked');
if(isChecked ){
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='title[]']").prop('checked', true);
}
else{
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='title[]']").prop('checked', false);
}
});
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kwmLok4t/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this by JS..

```
 <?php
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="id[]"> <input type="checkbox" name="title[]" id="chk2">';
    ?>
<script>
      $('#chk1').click(function(){
         if($("#chk1:checked").length)
             $('#chk2').prop('checked', true);
      });
</script>
```

Comment: how to do it in loop form?

Comment: make the unique id for all the elements and call a function with ID as parameter and make it happen..

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS Code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check">

<input type="checkbox" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk">
<input type="checkbox" class="chk">
<script>

var x=document.getElementById('check').checked;
if(x==true)
{
 var length=document.getElementsByClassName('chk').length; 
 for(i=0;i<=length; i++)
{
 document.getElementsByClassName('chk')[i].checked=true;
}    
}
else
{
 var length=document.getElementsByClassName('chk').length; 
 for(i=0;i<=length; i++)
{
 document.getElementsByClassName('chk')[i].checked=true;
}

}

</script>
```